# C# after set amount of seconds change

Tags: c#, 2d, sprite

I've been looking for some code for a while now with no success.

I have it so that after I press the space bar my sprite changes to a different sprite and then once I press the space bar again it changes back to the original sprite.

I just need some code so that about 3 seconds after I press the space bar the first time and the sprite changes, the sprite changes back to its original set.

Ive been looking at timers and countdown timers and non of it is what im looking for.

any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: I assume you're making a game. Are you using an engine that keeps track of delta time between each frame?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you have tried with timers and why it is not what you're looking for?  That seems like a straightforward solution to this problem.

Comment: I've been looking at lots of the timers and stopwatches on this site and nothing seems to fit the bill, i'm still pretty new the C# so that's probably part of my problem. I'm using the free version of Unity and I remember making a timer in some Java script about a year ago that when the timer hit 3 seconds it would spawn a new actor then reset itself, im not sure how to recreate that in C#

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the Stopwatch class and do something like this?

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); // sw cotructor
sw.Start(); // starts the stopwatch
while(true)
{
    sw.Stop(); // stop the time measurement
    if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 3000) // check if desired period of time has elapsed
         break; // stop looping and return
    else
         sw.Start(); // resume stopwatch
}
```